# Using find to find files

Tags: linux, command-line, cygwin, find

If I'm in the root directory, can I use find to search all the directories below it for a file?

I tried find stdio.h but it didn't find anything.  However I know that that file is in the filesystem somewhere.  How do I find it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's in `/usr/include/stdio.h`, but for future reference run

```
$ locate stdio.h
```

Don't forget to run `updatedb` first. On Cygwin, you'll want to run it as Administrator.

To look in the current directory and its children:

```
$ find . -name stdio.h
```

To look everywhere beneath the root directory:

```
$ find / -name stdio.h
```

You tagged this as a Cygwin question, so to search the entire C drive, you could run

```
$ find /cygdrive/c -name stdio.h
```

but that's likely to be much slower than searching from an Explorer window.