# How can I perform these 2 file search using Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, search, grep

how can I do a search like these into bash shell?

1) Search all files that start having name starting with **mysql-** (and then something else) into a specific folder (and all its subfolder)

2) Search if into some files (configuration\textual) into a specific folder there is the content  starting with **mysql-** (and then something else)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using find to find files](https://superuser.com/questions/73932/using-find-to-find-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confused, however as I understand it as:

1) You want to find all files starting with `mysql-` in specific folder(directory) and it's subtree:

```
find <your directory here> -name "mysql-*"
```

2) Find all files in specified directory which contain `mysql-`:

```
cd <your directory here> && grep -R mysql- *
```

if you really want just filenames, add cut filter:

```
cd <your directory here> && grep -R mysql- * | cut -d ":" -f1 | sort | uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

1. use `find` command :

   ```
   find MYDIR -iname mysql-* -type f
   ```
2. use `grep` command :

   ```
   grep -rn 'mysql-' MYDIR
   ```